# why isn't rails using rabl as the template engine for a json response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

i'm still not that familiar with rails so this could be a simple thing i've neglected to do. i have rabl installed and working on a dev server, i've just tried it on a prod server and it's not working. the environments are identical on each machine.

rails 2.3.14, rabl 0.7.6

the error i'm seeing is ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template asset_links/index.erb in view path app/views):

in my controller i've got require 'rabl' , in the console ::Rabl is defined. in the index action of the controller i'm calling render

```
  :rabl => @asset_links
```

since the template rails is looking for is index.erb and not index.rabl, that leads me to believe Rabl is not registered somehow?

i installed rabl many months ago on my dev server and don't remember any extra steps required to make it render json. any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your production server probably hasn't picked up the rabl gem.
Make sure that rabl is installed on your server and make sure your server has been restarted.
If you are using unicorn with rvm then unicorn may well not be picking up the gemset you are expecting it to